# How can I build/deploy twice for a single branch?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I need to set up a demo server, which is a copy of the production server, but pointed at a different API.  I want to run 2 separate build/deploy whenever the main branch is updated to accomplish this, as I need to run the demo build (Vue) to use different env variables pointing at the demo API (which will also need a dual deploy).  Is this possible, and how would I go about it?  Here's the existing:

```
stages:
- build
- deploy
- test

include:
- template: Security/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml
- template: Security/Secret-Detection.gitlab-ci.yml

build-main:
  image: node:12
  stage: build
  only:
  - main
  script:
  - yarn global add @quasar/cli
  - rm package-lock.json
  - yarn
  - npm run build:prod
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 hour
    paths:
    - dist
deploy-main:
  stage: deploy
  only:
  - main
  script:
  - echo $CI_PROJECT_DIR
  - whoami
  - sudo rsync -rav --exclude '.git' $CI_PROJECT_DIR/dist/spa/. /var/www/console
  tags:
  - deploy
build-beta:
  image: node:12
  stage: build
  only:
  - beta
  script:
  - yarn global add @quasar/cli
  - rm package-lock.json
  - yarn
  - npm run build:beta
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 hour
    paths:
    - dist
deploy-beta:
  stage: deploy
  only:
  - beta
  script:
  - echo $CI_PROJECT_DIR
  - whoami
  # - sudo /usr/local/bin/rsync -rav --exclude '.git' $CI_PROJECT_DIR/dist/spa/. /var/www/console.beta  
  - sudo rsync -rav --exclude '.git' $CI_PROJECT_DIR/dist/spa/. /var/www/console.beta
  tags:
  - deploy
build-dev:
  image: node:12
  stage: build
  only:
  - dev
  script:
  - yarn global add @quasar/cli
  - rm package-lock.json
  - yarn
  - npm run build:dev
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 hour
    paths:
    - dist
deploy-dev:
  stage: deploy
  only:
  - dev
  script:
  - echo $CI_PROJECT_DIR
  - whoami
  - sudo rsync -rav --exclude '.git' $CI_PROJECT_DIR/dist/spa/. /var/www/console.dev
  tags:
  - deploy
sast:
  stage: test
  artifacts:
    reports:
      sast: gl-sast-report.json
    paths:
    - 'gl-sast-report.json'
```

Comment: If I'm understanding your question, it seems like if you switch `only:-dev` to `only: [dev, main]` it would do what you want. Maybe also expand the stages to order them or declare `needs:`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following ,that will create 2 build jobs and 2 deploy jobs, that are linked together using `needs`:

```yaml
stages:
- build
- deploy

build-main:
  stage: build
  script: echo
  only:
    - main
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 hour
    paths:
    - dist
deploy-main:
  stage: deploy
  script: echo
  only:
    - main
  needs:
    - job: build-main
      artifacts: true
build-demo:
  stage: build
  script: echo
  only:
    - main
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 hour
    paths:
    - dist
deploy-demo:
  stage: deploy
  script: echo
  only:
    - main
  needs:
    - job: build-demo
      artifacts: true
```

you might also want to extract common jobs to hidden jobs to simplify your pipeline, for instance:

```yaml
stages:
- build
- deploy

.build:
  stage: build
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 hour
    paths:
    - dist

build-main:
  extends: .build
  only: main
  # other specific codes
```

Also you might want to improve readability and management of [workflow rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#workflow) like the following, which will centralize rules logics:

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      variables:
        DEPLOY_PROD: "true"
        DEPOLOY_DEMO: "true"
        # Some other conditional variables
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "dev"
      variables:
        DEPLOY_DEV: "true"
    - when: always   

build-main:
    rules:
    - if: $DEPLOY_PROD

# other jobs
```